# Does Rego Set lookup will iterate all items in the set?

Tags: open-policy-agent, rego

```
package example

default allow = false

input = {
    "value_2": {"c", "b", "c", "b", "c", "b", "c", "b", "c", "b", "c", "b", "c", "b", "c", "b", "c", "b", "c", "b", "c", "a", "a"},
    "value_1": ["c", "b", "c", "b", "c", "b", "c", "b", "c", "b", "c", "b", "c", "b", "c", "b", "c", "b", "c", "b", "c", "a", "a"]
}

allow {
    input.value_1[_] == "a"
    input.value_2["a"] == "a"
}
```

follow the example, which one will do the lookup faster?

Answer (score 0):

Set lookup is constant time:

```
a_set["a"]  # <-- this is constant time
```

Iteration and comparison of set elements is not (currently) optimized and is linear-time:

```
a_set[_] == "a" # <-- this is linear-time
```

The example above though is not valid because `input.value_2` is defined as an *array* (not a *set*) so `input.value_2["a"]` is invalid. If you try this example you'll receive a type error from the compiler:

```
1 error occurred: policy.rego:12: rego_type_error: undefined ref: data.example.input.value_2.a
    data.example.input.value_2.a
                               ^
                               have: "a"
                               want (type): number
```

Assuming you wanted to use a *set* originally, just use the lookup syntax (`s[k]`) and do not bother with the additional equality check (unless you're testing for whether `false` is contained in the set, but that would be odd.)

Note, the [Policy Reference](https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/policy-reference/) page on the OPA website explains how to perform lookups, comparison, and iteration on arrays, objects, and sets.